# How to add websocket app as part to my existing project Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I have Spring Boot app, and I found interessting example of websocket chat.

I tried to add this: https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-websocket-chat-demo

But it is not working for me if I try to do link to my `chat.html` page from `Freemarker` template page.

For example, on my `main page` I have 2 links to other paths with other templates. But I want to add link to `static html page` with native javascript. How can I implement that?

I tried to add to `ChatController` `GetMapping("/chat")` (but it is not the part of java logic, as its static code), so it did not work for me.

When I open that path I receive:

```
context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for class org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageHeaderAccessor] with root cause
```

Without controller (`GetMapping("/chat")`).:

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
```

If I do vise versa - add links from `websocket app page` to `Freemarker` templates - it is working.